# Can I pass the content of the batch file directly as argument instead of saving it in a batch file and passing the file itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file, sftp, putty, psftp

Can I pass the content of the batch file directly as argument instead of saving it in a batch file and passing the file itself?
My question is the following, instead of using this:

```
psftp.exe user_name@host_domain -pw user_pw -b example_batch_file.bat
```

example_batch_file.bat content:

```
get filename.csv
```

I would like to use something like this (in one go, not manually opening the console and doing it one after another, its for automatisation purpose):

```
psftp.exe user_name@host_domain -pw user_pw -get filename.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The psftp can read the commands from the standard input.

So you can do:

```
(
  echo get filename.csv
  echo other command
) | psftp.exe user_name@host_domain -pw user_pw
```

If you really need one-liner, then:

```
( echo get filename.csv && echo other command ) | psftp.exe user_name@host_domain -pw user_pw
```

---

Though note that psftp also reads answers to its prompts from the standard input. So you will want to add [`-batch` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-usage-options-batch) to disable all prompts and make `psftp` automatically fail instead.